# autoupdate a list in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, inotifypropertychanged

I want to display a bunch of Objects i have created in a ListBox. My objects implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.
I tried to use an ObservableCollection, which i have bound to a listbox Control (listbox1.DataContext = MyCollection)
But this does not exactly what i want to do, because the Listbox is not refreshed when one of the properties of one of my objects in MyCollection changes.
I have found this blogposting: http://sweux.com/blogs/psampaio/index.php/2009/04/13/creating-a-custom-observable-collection-in-wpf

is this realy the easyiest/only way to keep track of several objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but have you tried using a datatemplate for your listbox items? like, a textbox that explicitly sets it's text to the appropriate binding.

Comment: that was the solution, thx. Sometimes i feel dumb and blind... :-/

Comment: Was just a wild guess. actually, right now i have noticed that's why the listbox in my own app isn't updating either.